# Combine two tables and sum a column if matching date and id pair exists

Tags: mysql

I am trying to perform a MYSQL/SQL query which combines two tables into one, so that only the rows with matching 'date' and 'id' get added together ('count' summed up). Any row in the table1 that doesn't have matching 'date' and 'id' pair in table2 gets added as is.

The tables I am combining are TABLE1 and TABLE2, resulting in TABLE_COMBINED. What is the best way to perform this kind of table coupling?

Examples of the table formats and the wanted result below:

TABLE1

```
date        |    count  |   id  |
```

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   100 |   5   |

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   10  |   6   |

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   20  |   7   |

...

TABLE2

```
date        |    count  |   id  |
```

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   29  |   5   |

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   20  |   6   |

2003-04-15 01:38:00     |   10  |   8   |

...

Combine TABLE1 and TABLE2. Sum 'count' of both tables if 'date' and 'id' match.

TABLE_COMBINED

```
date        |    count  |   id  |
```

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   129 |   5   |

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   30  |   6   |

2002-04-15 01:38:00     |   20  |   7   |

2003-04-15 01:38:00     |   10  |   8   |

Comment: Before asking question on SO, you're meant to show that you have actually researched the question and tried to find an answer yourself, which doesn't seem to be the case here, especially considering that the answer is quite straightforward in this case.

Comment: What you're looking for is JOINing of tables. There are tons of sources giving you a perfect answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your notes. I was browsing previous answers for a while and couldn't find answer that would suit my needs. Probably because I wasnt aware of the right terminology (join_ing tables) :) . 

I am very new to database handling and sql/mysql stuff as its not my main focus area. The answer below and your notes lead me to right direction, so thanks!

Comment: @bouscher In this case, a join isn't quite as straight forward as it would seem, since MySQL is (sadly) missing `FULL OUTER JOIN` :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily using `UNION ALL` to get all the rows and `GROUP` them just as if you were only selecting from a single table;

```sql
SELECT `date`, SUM(`count`) `count`, `id`
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Table2
) a
GROUP BY `date`, `id`
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bb51/2).

Comment: Thanks! This was easier than I expected.